# AC dimmer Code bulb does not glow before blinking

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, arduino-c++

I Am having problems in my code... i am using a ac dimmer module with arduino and i want to make the light glow for 5sec and then blink twice then repeat

```
int AC_LOAD = 3;    // Output to Opto Triac pin
int dimming = 128;  // Dimming level (0-128)  0 = ON, 128 = OFF

void setup()
{
  pinMode(AC_LOAD, OUTPUT);// Set AC Load pin as output
  attachInterrupt(0, zero_crosss_int, RISING);  // Choose the zero cross interrupt # from the table above
}

//the interrupt function must take no parameters and return nothing
void zero_crosss_int()  //function to be fired at the zero crossing to dim the light
{
  // Firing angle calculation : 1 full 50Hz wave =1/50=20ms 
  // Every zerocrossing thus: (50Hz)-> 10ms (1/2 Cycle) 
  // For 60Hz => 8.33ms (10.000/120)
  // 10ms=10000us
  // (10000us - 10us) / 128 = 75 (Approx) For 60Hz =>65

  int dimtime = (75*dimming);    // For 60Hz =>65    
  delayMicroseconds(dimtime);    // Wait till firing the TRIAC    
  digitalWrite(AC_LOAD, HIGH);   // Fire the TRIAC
  delayMicroseconds(10);         // triac On propogation delay 
         // (for 60Hz use 8.33) Some Triacs need a longer period
  digitalWrite(AC_LOAD, LOW);    // No longer trigger the TRIAC (the next zero crossing will swith it off) TRIAC
}

void loop() 


{
 {
   int e = 5;
   dimming = e;
   delay(200);
 }
  {
  for (int i=128; i >= 5; i--){
  dimming=i;
  delay(2);
  }

  for (int j=5; j <= 128; j++){
  dimming=j;           
  delay(2); // this value is the light delay timing 
  }
  //delay(3);  // this value is the gap timing 


  for (int i=128; i >= 5; i--){
  dimming=i;
  delay(2);
  }

  for (int j=5; j <= 128; j++){
  dimming=j;           
  delay(2); // this value is the light delay timing 
  }
  //delay(3);  // this value is the gap timing 
  }}
```

when i use this code the light doesnt glow for 5 sec and then blink . it gets a 5 sec delay and then blinks

```
{
   int e = 5;
   dimming = e;
   delay(200);
 }
```

but if i use only this part of the code with the codes below it. it glows

i am really new to programming please help me out

Comment: delay() has milliseconds not seconds

Comment: In loop() you are writing a lot of numbers into `dimming`. Your compiler may optimize away a number of those write accesses because -as known to the compiler- nowhere is read from the variable. Try declare `dimming` as `volatile` so **every** change is surely written and **can** be seen by the ISR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 5 second delay you're observing is the boot time of the Arduino. Arduinos bootloader will wait for new firmeware befor your sketch is executed.

If you want to have your light on for 5 seconds, replace `delay(200);` by `delay(5000);`.